# Contar cantidad de veces que aparece un elementos de una lista Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo python y en este ejercicio, tengo que contar la cantidad de veces que aparece un elemento e en una lista dada por la funcion:

```
def buscar_n_elemento(lista,e):
   for i in lista:
       if lista[i]==e:
           lista.count('e')
       return i 

print(buscar_n_elemento([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6], 3))
```

Pero siempre me devuelve 1, cuando para el elemento 3 deberia ser 2 la cantidad de veces! alguien podria ayudarme? Gracias!

Comment: en lugar de esto lista.count('e') que sea un counter++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ejemplo 1:

```
def buscar_n_elemento(lista, e):
   contador=0
   for i in lista:
      if i == e:
         contador+=1
   return contador

print(buscar_n_elemento([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3))
```

2. Ejemplo 2:

```
print([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6].count(3))
```

Comment: muchas gracias!